# Javascript Vanilla - Pegar valor select multiple e montar em json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<button id="get">Estilos</button>

<select id="estilos-select" multiple>
  <option value="1">Sertanejo</option>
  <option value="2">MPB</option>
  <option value="3">Samba</option>
  <option value="4">Pagode</option>
</select>
```

Tenho o select multipla escolha, no qual preciso pegar os valores e montar num json. Com jQuery faço o seguinte:

```
$("#get").click(function(){
    let data = {};
    data['id_estilo'] = JSON.stringify($('#estilos-select').val())
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

E o resultado é {"id_estilo":"[\"1\",\"2\"]"}

Como consigo o mesmo resultado com javascript puro?
Sei que precisa colocar num for, mas como faço o array dentro da chave "id_estilo"?

```
let data = {}
for (let i=0; i<estilos.length; i++){
    data.id_estilo['id_estilo'] = estilos[i].value
}
```

Essa linha, por exemplo nao dá certo, ou mesmo se eu fizer `data.id_estilo['id_estilo'].push(estilos[i].value)`

Comment: mas se está usando jquery não é javascript vanilla :)

Comment: Justamente, preciso traduzir esse código pra js puro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O exemplo simples com vanilha é fazer um `loop` no `options` do `select` e verificar quais itens estão selecionados, exemplo:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("get");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var select = document.getElementById("estilos-select");
  var items = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++)
  {
    if (select.options[i].selected)
    {
      items.push(select.options[i].value);
    }
  }
  obj = { id_estilo: items };
  console.log(obj);
});
```

```html
<button id="get">Estilos</button>

<select id="estilos-select" multiple>
  <option value="1">Sertanejo</option>
  <option value="2">MPB</option>
  <option value="3">Samba</option>
  <option value="4">Pagode</option>
</select>
```